# How can I fire an ActionEvent from a different JComponent?

Tags: java, actionlistener, listeners, actionevent

I have a JTextField with an ActionListener registered to it. When this JTextField has focus, and the enter key is pressed, an ActionEvent is created.

How can I link this event to another components ActionListener, like a JButton, so I can run its code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have each action listener just call the same function. For example,

```
 public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
    myModel.actOnButtonOrTextEvent( e );
 }
```

Comment: That works, but I ended up just calling the button's doClick() method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up calling the button's doClick() method.